# How can I get EC2 instance metadata using Spring Cloud v3?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-aws

I am working on a Java / Spring Boot / Spring application which was using Version 1 of the AWS Java SDK and version 2.4.4 of io.awspring.cloud.

This application is using the class `io.awspring.cloud.core.env.ec2.AmazonEc2InstanceDataPropertySource` like this, to get the AMI ID for the EC2 instance:

```java
var amazonEc2InstanceDataPropertySource = new AmazonEc2InstanceDataPropertySource("xxx");

String amiId = getInstanceDataProperty(amazonEc2InstanceDataPropertySource,"ami-id", "N/A");
```

..and so on for other properties.

I have now upgraded this application to version 2 of the AWS Java SDK and version 3.0.2 of `io.awspring.cloud`. In the new version of `io.awspring.cloud` there is no class called `AmazonEc2InstanceDataPropertySource`.

How can I rewrite the existing code to work in the new version of this library to get EC2 instance metadata?

Comment: It seems you're trying to obtain the AMI ID for the current EC2 instance that the application is running on, correct? The latest docs of Spring Cloud seem to do this in the ['Java' way](https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/2.3.2/reference/html/index.html#retrieving-instance-metadata) as opposed to providing a class (though I haven't checked all of the codebase).

Comment: If that doesn't work for you, let me know and I can provide an answer on how to do this using just the AWS SDK.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary thanks very much this is the solution I needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AmazonEc2InstanceDataPropertySource` class fetches [EC2 instance metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html) properties via the IMDS (Instance Metadata Service), for the current EC2 instance.

It seems to have been replaced with [`@EnableContextInstanceData`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-aws-context/2.2.6.RELEASE/org/springframework/cloud/aws/context/config/annotation/EnableContextInstanceData.html) (not needed in Spring Boot with the [right configuration](https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/2.3.2/reference/html/index.html#enabling-instance-metadata-support-in-spring-boot)) & field injection using [`Value`](https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/2.3.2/reference/html/index.html#retrieving-instance-metadata) annotations.

In your case, as you're looking to get the AMI ID and other properties, inject these properties directly using the @Value annotation.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableContextInstanceData
public static class MyConfig {}
```

```java
@Value("${ami-id}")
private String amiId;

@Value("${hostname}")
private String hostname;

@Value("${instance-type}")
private String instanceType;

@Value("${services/domain}")
private String serviceDomain;
```